# Why is the acceleration of the string connected to the cylinder different from which the cylinder is moving forward with?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image: The figure of the system.]

The following Object 'B' is a ***cylinder***. It is kept **mounted horizontally** on a massless block, when a tension T is applied by a string passing over the lower end of cylinder, the ***acceleration of the string which is tied to the cylinder Is different from that of the acceleration with which the CENTRE OF MASS of mass of cylinder is moving forward with*** (i.e., the cylinder is experiencing both rotational and translocation motion). Please explain me why this happens.

Intutuively I can imagine that they are to be different, but can you please provide a proof of that.

Comment: Write an expression for the location of the end of the string (relative to the wall) as a function of how far the cylinder is from the wall.  Then imagine what happens when you change the distance by a small amount.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, at the point the string contacts the cylinder, their velocity and acceleration are the same (otherwise the string will slip).

Secondly say that the velocity of the center of the cylinder is $v$ and its angular velocity is $\omega$. At that point, its velocity will be $v+\omega\times r$. (why? Hint: Galileo transformation)

The same argument applies to acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all $$\vec{F_{ext}}=m\vec{a_{cm}}$$

This equation conveys us the messge that the net external force is the only force which is responsible for the acceleration of center of mass of the system.

It doesn't means that $\vec{a_{cm}}=\vec{a_{i}}$, where $\vec{a_{i}}$ represents the acceleration of $i^{th}$ particle of the system.